# Alert on Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a `Cosmos DB` to save application logs. Can I trigger `Azure Alert` on `Cosmos DB` when errors logs wrote into `Cosmos DB`? I'm struggling to search the answer from `Microsoft Docs` for a while, but still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to detect inserts in cosmosdb and trigger an alert. However

> Change feed support in Azure Cosmos DB works by listening to an Azure
>   Cosmos container for any changes.

You need to do at the [application level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed).

Comment: This is too much (heavy) to do. I've voted on your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Azure Alerts.

Click alerts in the Cosmos DB blade.

Create a new Alert on Total requests. Signal logic should look like this
[image]

Then add an action to email yourself.
[image]

Comment: Well, it seems the alert signal type can only be "Metrics" or "Activity Log", but no the content written into the cosmos DB. I want to trigger the alert based on the message/content written into the cosmos DB.

Comment: Then Sejeetharans answer is the correct one and you need to use Change Feed. Then for each read feed, inspect the contents and trigger your alert.